# Creating Tablet AVD shows error

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am trying to create 7" tablet from my AVD Manager. Configuration is as follows,

> [image]

But when I load my avd, It shows following error in DDMS,

```
03-31 09:12:17.840: E/AndroidRuntime(526): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-31 09:12:17.840: E/AndroidRuntime(526): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.android.systemui.SystemUIService: java.lang.RuntimeException: Tablet device cannot show navigation bar and system bar
03-31 09:12:17.840: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2263)
03-31 09:12:17.840: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-31 09:12:17.840: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
03-31 09:12:17.840: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-31 09:12:17.840: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-31 09:12:17.840: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-31 09:12:17.840: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 09:12:17.840: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-31 09:12:17.840: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-31 09:12:17.840: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-31 09:12:17.840: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-31 09:12:17.840: E/AndroidRuntime(526): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Tablet device cannot show navigation bar and system bar
03-31 09:12:17.840: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at com.android.systemui.statusbar.tablet.TabletStatusBar.makeStatusBarView(TabletStatusBar.java:451)
03-31 09:12:17.840: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBar.start(StatusBar.java:64)
03-31 09:12:17.840: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at com.android.systemui.statusbar.tablet.TabletStatusBar.start(TabletStatusBar.java:390)
03-31 09:12:17.840: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at com.android.systemui.SystemUIService.onCreate(SystemUIService.java:93)
03-31 09:12:17.840: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2253)
03-31 09:12:17.840: E/AndroidRuntime(526):  ... 10 more
```

What could be the reason for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Error Caused by this line:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Tablet device cannot show navigation bar and system bar
```

you can handle like below:

```
try {
         // Sanity-check that someone hasn't set up the config wrong and asked for a navigation
         // bar on a tablet that has only the system bar
         if (mWindowManager.hasNavigationBar()) {
             throw new RuntimeException(
                     "Tablet device cannot show navigation bar and system bar");
         }
     } catch (RemoteException ex) {
     }
```

Source [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/com/android/systemui/statusbar/tablet/TabletStatusBar.java#TabletStatusBar.makeStatusBarView%28%29)

Another way to resolve this, by changing configuration file:

```
put hw.mainKeys=yes in your .android->avd->youavdfoldername->config
open file and change hw.mainKeys=yes
```

Comment: Thank you Lokesh, can you tell me where I should write this code ?

Comment: where is that path ? I am not getting you yar.

Comment: have you find our .android folder?? for me it was C:/Users/Myname/.android/avd/myTabletName/config file..

Comment: I am busy at the moment, but I will surely update you on this. Right now I have used real tablet and my problem is solved.